# VoIP call monitor

Tags: monitoring, logs, voip

Can anyone recommend me a program to monitor VoIP calls, preferably for Windows. I would like for it to log caller-ID and if possible record the conversation.

If you have any suggestions, please give them. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify as to the nature of the VoIP calls?  Are you running Asterisk on your Synology, or, on the other end(s) of the spectrum, are you wanting to monitor Skype or call made via the VoIP service that comes with your cable provider's "Triple Play" package?

Answer (score -1):

You can try this tools for VOIP CALL [Monast](https://dagmoller.github.io/monast/#downloads)

This tools is open source and you can install and run with python on windows and you can listen the conversation.

Comment: Please add: License, whether it works on Windows, how to set it up to monitor VoIP calls. Thanks!